# error using multiselect with EChosen extension Yii

Tags: php, yii, dropdown, multipleselection

I'm using Yii and I want to make a multiselect dropdown by using EChosen extension.

Here is my form code:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'PROJ_PLATFORM', array('class'=>'control-label')); ?>
    <div class="controls"><?php 
            echo Chosen::multiSelect($model, 'PROJ_PLATFORM', (CHtml::listData (MstEmailBody::model()->getList(),'CODE_NM', 'CODE_NM')),
                array(
                'empty'=>'asdasdasd',
                   // 'data-placeholder' => 'Tags',
                   'options'=>array(
                      'maxSelectedOptions' => 3,
                      'displaySelectedOptions' => true,
                )));
        ?>
        <span class="help-inline text-error"><?php echo $form->error($model,'PROJ_PLATFORM'); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I got this error:

```
Object of class MstEmailBody could not be converted to string
```

What causes this error? I have brows but I still got no solution.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: this type of error accrue when we try to access object as string you can try simple way  `<?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->dropDownList(Stops::getUserlist(),['multiple'=>'multiple'] ) ?>` for multiselect

Comment: great this really help ful. but when i click save, the data don't want to be save. it said that `project platform is invalid`. is there any solution or smth that i have to do wtih? @ParitoshMahale

Comment: if you check in controller you will see that project_platform is in array. you need to combine it ( comma separated or loop out) to store it in database

Comment: which side should i edit? i add this code in `if($model->save()){....}` and above it but it still didn't work. this is the code i just create `$multi = $model->PROJ_PLATFORM;
    if(isset($multi)){
     foreach($multi as $banyak){
      $semua = implode(', ', $banyak);
     }
    }` @ParitoshMahale

Comment: it will be something like `$proj_platform_list = implode(",",$_POST['your_form_name_here']['PROJ_PLATFORM']);
$model->PROJ_PLATFORM = $proj_platform_list;
$model->save();`

Comment: my form name is `_form` so i just do `$proj_platform_list = implode(",",$_POST['_form']['PROJ_PLATFORM']); $model->PROJ_PLATFORM = $proj_platform_list; $model->save();` this? but this still don't work. and even i put this outside my `if($model->save())` it return error undefined `_form` @ParitoshMahale

Comment: `_form` is not form name use `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST)` to print your post data and key upto 'PROJ_PLATFORM' (may be the form name is same as model name form belong to)

Comment: so should i put an ajax here to throw the value to the controller?

Comment: no, form always submit to particulate action in controller in actionCreate in`if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())` this condition add  `echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);die();` this code you will see all submitted data after form submission

Comment: i have tried that `echo"<pre>"; print_r .....` and this is the result `Array
(
    [MstEmailBody] => Array
        (
            [EMAIL_DESC] => percobaan
            [PROJ_PLATFORM] => MAGIC
            [EMAIL_CATEGORIZE] => 
            [PROJ_STATUS] => 
            [EMAIL_RECEIVED] => cobacoba@gmail.com
            [FLAG_ACTIVE] => N
        )

    [yt0] => Create
)` anyway i make the dropdown as single select to get the value. then i tried `$proj_platform_list = implode(",",$_POST['MstEmailBody']['PROJ_PLATFORM']);` but still failing @ParitoshMahale

Comment: try this`$proj_platform_list = implode(",",$_POST['MstEmailBody']['PROJ_PLATFORM']);
$model->PROJ_PLATFORM = $proj_platform_list;
$model->save();`

Comment: i put it in the wrong place and its done. thank you so much for helping! @ParitoshMahale

Comment: hello i just realize that i have another problem, when i update the data, multi select is not rendering the value. whats the problem? @ParitoshMahale

Comment: you need to follow revers process 1) query database and get comma separated PROJ_PLATFORM values 2)explode it and convert it to array 3)assign array to model `$model->PROJ_PLATFORM` and Yii takes care of other things

Comment: thanks alot!! i find your question before n try it. and it works..

Comment: how could i allow empty in the multiple select dropdown? @ParitoshMahale

Comment: sorry i don't follow. did you mean yo want to skip required validation ?

Comment: yes, so that if i didn't chose any, it still can save. because i just tried if i don't fill them it return error saying `unindentified PROJ_PLATFORM`. when i try to use `if(isset($_POST['PROJ_PLATFORM'])){$proj_platform_list .....}else {$model->PROJ_PLATFORM = ''}` it always give null value even i choose the drop down

Comment: you should try `if(isset($_POST['MstEmailBody']['PROJ_PLATFORM']))` insted of `if(isset($_POST['PROJ_PLATFORM']))`

Comment: i have tried it, but that return `project platform is invalid` just like before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this is the solution for my problem

veiw:

```
Chosen::activeMultiSelect($model, 'PIC_BSA', (CHtml::listData (MstResource::model()->getListBsa(),'RES_CD', 'RES_NM')),
                    array(
                       // 'data-placeholder' => 'Tags',
                       'options'=>array(
                          // 'maxSelectedOptions' => 3,
                          'displaySelectedOptions' => true,
                    )));
```

form:

```
echo $form->dropDownlist($model,'PIC_BSA', 
                        (CHtml::listData (MstResource::model()->getListBsa(),'RES_CD','RES_NM')),
                            array(
                            'multiple'=>true,
                            ));
```

controller:

```
$model->PIC_BSA = explode(",", $model->PIC_BSA);
if(isset($_POST['TrnProjectIT']['PIC_BSA'])){
                $pic_bsa = implode(",",$_POST['TrnProjectIT']['PIC_BSA']);
                $model->PIC_BSA = $pic_bsa;
            }else{
                $model->PIC_BSA = '';
            }
```